# Program runs within eclipse IDE but will not run as a jar file

Tags: java

My program runs fine within the eclipse ide. When I try to run it as a jar file I get the following message:

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.noClassFoundError:
>   org/apache/logging/logfactory  at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.defaultHostNameVerifier.(BotTest.java:65) at BotTest.main(BotTest.java:100)
>   Caused by:Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I do have 4 libraries in the project and I use the option 
"Extract required libraries into generated jar".

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the jar? Can you verify that the libraries' classes are copied into your jar? You can open it with any archiving tool.

Comment: Likely you've not set up your manifest file, especially its class path. Have you searched on this problem before asking? I ask because there are a lot of similar posts on this site.

Comment: Hi Thank you about telling my I could un archive my jar file.  I found that one of the lib is missing.  If I go to build paths on eclipse it has 4 lib, but the jar file only has 3.  I looked on google but gthe sercahes all came up with stuff about adding jars to a project not producing them.  Any thoughts on why eclipse is not putting all 4 lib in the jar file????

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using extract required libraries into generated jar, select "package required library into generated JAR" option. It will work.

Comment: I tried that did not worckm but thanks for trying to help me

Comment: 2 more stuff which you can try: (a) all the dependent project / jar must be in this current project build path (b) while generating jar, proper launch configuration must be set.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you may not be properly setting up the manifest file to recognize your library jar files. The manifest file should have a line that looks something like:

```
Class-Path: some.jar other.jar third.jar
```

Please also check out the [many similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+jar+file+ClassNotFoundException+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).